# import custom coordinates relative to two points

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am measuring location of objects on a property, and I have a file with their coordinates (x,y) relative to two points of origin, which are two corners of the house.
Is it possible to create a custom projection (or another method) to be able to import all these points at once.
For now I am just intersecting two circles, and it's really impractical.
[image]
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am unsure what your data is supposed to look like, could you give us a clear example of your input data? Otherwise, the simplest solution would be a little python script imo.

Comment: Hi @LouisCottereau my date is table with x and y. 
(25,6, 12,6)
(23,3, 56,7)
etc
and the origin of these coordindates are the corners of the houses (center of green circles on my screenshot)

Comment: Yeah I got that part but how do you know in your input data if your coordinate (x,y) are relative to the first point or the second? what is your source ? csv, vector layer table, ...? do you have a vector layer with the two origine/reference points?

Comment: Also, you cannot really create a point from two set of coordinates you have to use one or the other. But then how accurate are the coordinates and do you want to average out the two points that will be created by both set of coordinates ?

Comment: First coordinate x, is always relative to x0 (I edited the image), and second coordinate y is relative to y0 (as shown on the image). The data can be arranged in any format. Csv would be easy. I don't have a vector layer with the two origin points but it can be created.

Comment: There is just one set of coordinates. one couple (x,y) for each point.

Answer (score 0):

This script will do what you want, might need some slight tinkering depending on what you have (csv path, delimiter in csv (','/';'/...))

```py
import csv 

point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("point_layer")[0]
point_layer_output = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "points", "memory")
point_layer_output.setCrs(point_layer.crs())

origin_point_x, origin_point_y = list(point_layer.getFeatures())
pt0x = origin_point_x.geometry().asPoint().x()
pt0y = origin_point_y.geometry().asPoint().y()

feats = []

with open(r"coordinates.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';')

    for row in reader:
        pt = QgsPointXY(pt0x + float(row['x']), pt0y + float(row["y"]))
        feature = QgsFeature(point_layer_output.fields())
        feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(pt))
        feats.append(feature)

point_layer_output.dataProvider().addFeatures(feats)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(point_layer_output)
```

This csv:
[image]

will give this result:
[image]